# Flipping 3 unfair coins. Chance of getting heads $N$ times

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I am given three unfair coins, with the chance of flipping heads for each coin being:

$$
p_1=0.6, 
p_2=0.3, 
p_3=0.1
$$

If each coin is flipped once, what is the probability of getting heads $N$ times?
What if each coin is flipped $M$ times?

Thanks!

---

My chance of solving it:

Each coin is flipped M times, meaning that the total number of flips is 3M. The number of ways in which N heads can be realized is
$$
{3M \choose N}
$$

If this was 1 coin, I would just use a Bernoulli distribution - but it is at this point I am stuck since we have 3 coins that are unfair.

Comment: Please include your attempts at this question

Comment: I have included my thinking and where I am stuck. Thank you

Comment: Can you solve the first task? It should be easier to solve than the more general problem with $M$ flips.

Comment: What is the origin of this problem? This has the same distribution as Bin(M,p1)+Bin(M,p2)+Bin(M,p3) . Do you expect this to be solvable analytically?